# scrapy error: /usr/local/bin/scrapy: No such file or directory

Tags: python, scrapy

I just installed scrapy on a ubuntu instance, and I'm trying to trigger it from a bash comman like, I created a .sh file:

```
/usr/local/bin/scrapy crawl my_spider
```

But I get this error:

/usr/local/bin/scrapy: No such file or directory

I tried this:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/scrapy /usr/bin/
```

But I'm still getting the same error

The result for

```
 pip show Scrapy
```

Is:

```
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

But if I try:

```
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy crawl...
```

then it says that it is a directory

Comment: try to create a virtual environment, then install scrapy there and then proceed with above mentioned steps

Comment: You can find scrapy executable using `which scrapy` command

Comment: Does it work if you write just `scrapy` instead of `/usr/local/bin/scrapy`?

Comment: If write just `scray crawl you_spider` ?

Comment: @AlexVasquez No, it does not

Comment: @Gallaecio  No, it does not

Comment: How did you install Scrapy? Have you tried reinstalling? Does the output of the installation command mention how to run Scrapy afterwards, or additional steps to take? Have you considered using a virtual environment as suggested by @prashantrana instead of installing Scrapy globally?